# ctags file for several languages

Tags: ctags

I am using universal-ctags to generate a tags file that allows me traverse the code.

However the code base I am using spans verilog to C code. My question is this:

Can I have the one ctags file that has tags for several sw code bases in a repo ?

If not what is the alternative ? How would I dynamically select the tags file that I need at that present time ?

thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I have created a tags for verilog. I have read the documentation however can't extract if it is possible. I did come across an append reference in etags in one article but with the abundance of articles that I have read, I have lost that article

Comment: I'm mainly asking because universal ctags does what you want *by default* so it's unclear what you're doing to inhibit that.  You should show what you're doing in the question, as it's a confusing question at present.

Comment: On this page https://emacs-lsp.github.io/lsp-mode/page/languages/ there are two lsp-verilog modules/servers which can be useful instead of ctags.